# Counting numbers

Tags: combinatorics

How many numbers less than $1000$ can be formed using the digits $0,2,5,8,9$ when repetition is allowed. I proceeded as follows:

1 digit numbers: $5$

2 digit numbers: $4\times5=20$

3 digit numbers: $4\times5\times5=100$

So answer should be $100+20+5=125$. But the answer is given as $124$. What mistake am I committing?

Comment: How can we know what mistake you are making if you don't explain how you got your answer.

Maybe you are forgetting to count 0 as a 1 digit number?

Comment: Oh! *you* got 125 and the *stated answer* was 124.  I got those backwards.

Your answer is correct if you count 0 as a 1 digit number and the stated answer is wrong.  But, I suspect, if you reread the problem it probably states either between 1 and 1000 or *natural* numbers (not 0).  Or, maybe the editor screwed up.  Your answer is correct reasoning *if* we include 0 and the way the problem is stated we should.

Answer (score 2):

The answer looks correct if you count $0$ as a valid example (which it seems to be).

You outlined the cases correctly:  $5 + 20 + 100 = 125$.  I don't see where you're getting $124$.

Answer (score 1):

What numbers are you adding to get $125$? If I were to hazard a guess, I'd think you were perhaps extending the prohibition against $0$ as an initial number to the single digit case. If that's the case, you might be adding $4+20+100=124$.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, pop quiz.  How many numbers are less than 1000?

Did you answer a) 999 (because 1 - 999), b) 1000 (because 0 is a number) or c) infinite (because it said *numbers*, not positive integers).

So we need to read the authors mind.  Did s/he mean positive whole numbers?  If so the answer is 124 because 0 doesn't count.  If s/he meant anything else than the answer is 125 because 0 does count and we can only form non-negative integers.